# Showing no error but blank in choropleth map using folium

Tags: python, folium, choropleth

I am getting a blank output from the choropleth map.

I have tried different versions of joining jsan data but nothing working as the output remains blank

```
state_geo = f'san-francisco.geojson'
folium.Choropleth(
geo_data=state_geo,
data=df2,
columns= ['Neighbourhood','Count'],
key_on='feature.properties.DISTRICT',
fill_color='YlOrRd',
fill_opacity=0.7,
line_opacity=0.2,
legend_name='Crime rate in san Francisco'
).add_to(sanfran_map)
```

df2

Neighbourhood   Count
BAYVIEW         14303
CENTRAL         17666
INGLESIDE       11594
MISSION         19503
NORTHERN        20100
PARK             8699
RICHMOND        8922
SOUTHERN        28445
TARAVAL         11325
TENDERLOIN      9942

Also the json file

https://cocl.us/sanfran_geojson[enter link description here](https://cocl.us/sanfran_geojson.)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnU66.png)

expected result is a choropleth map

Comment: json file is : https://cocl.us/sanfran_geojson

Answer (score 0):

Do not create choropleth maps in Internet Explorer. Codes are fine they work as intended in Chrome.

Thanks